# Is it possible that the value of a continuous mother wavelet at origin is zero, i.e. $\psi(t=0)=0$?

Tags: continuous-signals, wavelet

According to Fourier transform, a continuous wavelet could be written as
$$
\psi(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\hat\psi(k)\text{e}^{-ikt}\text{d}k
$$

From the equation above, we know that $\psi(t=0)$ is
$$
\psi(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\hat\psi(k)\text{d}k
$$

Is it possible that  $\psi(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: a sufficient criterion for a valid wavelet is being zero mean in time domain, i.e. $\hat \psi (0) = 0$. For $\psi(0) = 0$ we require that $\hat \psi$ sums to zero; one example is higher order [Generalized Morse Wavelets](https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/generalized-morse-wavelets/) - from [Olhede & Walden](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/1150/1/OlhedeWaldenGenMorse.pdf),

[image]

(Though above is only approximately zero-sum). Such wavelets can be admissible and analytic, enabling [CWT](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Continuous_wavelet_transform) inversion. Trivial Python example below; GMWs are also implemented in [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/0.6.1/ssqueezepy/_gmw.py).

[image]

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import ifft, ifftshift

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 256, endpoint=False)
wf = np.exp(-(t - .08)**2 * 4096)
wf -= np.roll(wf, 25)    # shift by 25 samples and subtract
w = ifftshift(ifft(wf))  # take to time domain and center

plt.plot(wf)
plt.show()

plt.plot(w.real)
plt.plot(w.imag)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perfectly possible.
That means that the mean of the function $\hat{\psi}(k)$ is zero.