# Finding phase of a received signal using spectrogram function

Tags: python, phase, spectrogram

I am trying to find the phase of my dataset between a range of frequencies. I can't post my code or data but generally speaking, the frequencies range from 10 to 100kHz and I need the phase between 20 and 30kHz.

The data is read into Python as real numbers in the form of 64-bit floats. I was thinking to first pass the data through a spectrogram and set the mode to `angle` or `phase`. My first question is, I see from the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) the difference between the angle and phase modes is the wrapping. I'm not sure which to use so what do I need to consider when choosing one?

Second, how should I choose the parameters of the spectrogram to get the correct phase i.e. how should I choose the overlap number, fft length and window?

Lastly, once I have the complex angle returned by the spectrogram function, what operations do I need to do to recover the phase in degrees? Or, is there a better way to do this that does not use the spectrogram function?

Thank you

Comment: I also assume you confused "spectrogram" with "STFT", is that correct? `spectrogram = abs(stft)`. If not, the problem is much more challenging. If yes, then "spectrogram" should be changed to "STFT" everywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. If complex-valued STFT is of interest, preferably (and in this case definitely) [avoid](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86938/50076) scipy, librosa, MATLAB; the only suitable STFT implementation I know of is ssqueezepy's (disclaimer, am author).
2. Any `hop_size > 1` will alias STFT, and unlike for a spectrogram, it's always deleterious for phase extraction, unless aliased phase is acceptable.
3. No one method can handle all signals, since time-frequency decomposition is [non-unique](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84144/50076), hence so is phase decomposition. If your signal is expected to be composed of sufficiently separated AM-FMs, then time-frequency methods (STFT, CWT) will work well, and an upgrade can be [synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076).

I'll go with assumption in 3. The task is analogously "intrinsic mode" extraction, i.e. finding $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $x(t) = x_1(t) + x_2(t)$. This is accomplished by "carving" time-frequency; what this means, and tools to achieve it, are described [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83742/50076). ssqueezepy doesn't have a built-in carving function for non-SSQ_CWT, so the [one-integral inverse](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76239/50076) must be understood and tested on full-signal inverse if you are to write code for anything other than SSQ_CWT. For STFT it should suffice, however, to just correctly select the 2D coordinates.

Once inverses are obtained, it becomes standard phase recovery via the analytic signal - so in the referenced post, exclude the `.real` step, and apply `angle` and handle unwrapping (e.g. `np.unwrap`, but search around the site for more info to be sure).

#### Demo

Adding below code to [ridge_chirp.py](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/examples/ridge_chirp.py) produces:

[image]

where `hilbert` would not be needed if `issq_cwt` didn't use `.real`. Note, "recovered" is from "original" plus WGN with variance 2.

```py
# NOTE: also use `noise_var = 2`
from scipy.signal import hilbert

po, prec = [np.unwrap(np.angle(hilbert(g))) for g in (xo, xrec)]
pkw = dict(show=1, w=.6, h=.8, xlabel="time [sec]")
plot(ts, xo)
plot(ts, xrec, title="Signal: original vs recovered", **pkw)
plot(ts, po)
plot(ts, prec, title="Phase: Original vs recovered",  **pkw)
```

Comment: Okay, let me know if I understand correctly. You are suggesting first to find the components of the signal using "carving" time-frequency which requires the one integral inverse but to use that I need the inverse FFT of the signal? From there I can then just apply the $angle$ and $unwrap$ functions since I will have complex data?

Comment: Updated. No `ifft` is needed.

Comment: I can show how to carve STFT in a separate Q&A, if you show an attempt of trying for yourself ("ordering code" is off-topic).