# Filter amplifies frequencies at nyquist frequency. What's the purpose of such a filter?

Tags: python, finite-impulse-response, nyquist, highpass-filter

I'm currently facing a filter that amplifies frequencies at the Nyquist frequency. The sampling frequency is $f_s = 10$ Mhz.

What's a typical application for such a filter?

[image]

This is how I generated the plots:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fir(x, taps):
    # Convolve signal with filter coefficients
    return np.convolve(x, taps, mode="same")


def filt(x):
    # FIR filter coefficients
    taps = [-0.0625,  0.125,  -0.25,    0.5,    -0.25,    0.125,  -0.0625]
    
    # Apply FIR filter 
    return fir(x, taps)
    
    
def calc_fft(x, fs : float, N : int):
    # Perform FFT, truncate freqs above nyquist, and calc abs signal magnitude
    X = 2 * np.abs(np.fft.fft(x[:N], N))[0:N//2 + 1] / N
    
    # Correct DC component
    X[0] = X[0] / 2
    
    # Calculate frequency steps
    f = np.linspace(0, fs / 2, N // 2 + 1)
    
    return f, X

def plot_amp_freq_response(t, x, f, X, title : str = ""):
    # Create figure
    fig = plt.figure(title)
    fig.clf()
    
    # Create subplots
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
    
    # Plot results in time domain
    ax1.set_title(title)
    ax1.plot(t, x, '.-')
    ax1.set_xlabel("time [s]")
    ax1.set_ylabel("Magnitude")
    ax1.grid()
    
    # Plot results in frequency domain
    X_dB = 20*np.log10(X)
    ax2.plot(f, X_dB, '-')
    ax2.set_xlabel("freq [Hz]")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Magnitude [dB]")
    ax2.set_xscale('log')
    ax2.grid()
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()



###########################
# Filter Impulse Response #
###########################

def impulse_response(filter_func, title):
    # Sampling frequency
    fs = 10e6
    
    # Sampling period
    ts = 1 / fs
    
    # Number of samples
    N = 100
    
    # Generate Impulse
    x = np.zeros(N)
    x[10] = 1
    
    # Apply filter
    y = filter_func(x)
    
    # Response length
    N = len(y)
    
    # Generate sample points
    t = np.linspace(0, ts * N, N)
    
    # Calc FFT
    f, Y = calc_fft(y, fs, N)
    
    # Plot response
    plot_amp_freq_response(t, y, f, Y, title)
    
    return t, y, f, Y


# Filter System Impulse Response
t, y, f, Y = impulse_response(filt, "Filter System Impulse Response")

filter_response = np.trim_zeros(y)

print("INFO: Filter System Response: " + str(filter_response))
```

The program plots the frequency response plot and the FIR filter coefficients:

```
INFO: Filter System Response: [-0.0625  0.125  -0.25    0.5    -0.25    0.125  -0.0625]
```

Comment: something is amiss here: you cannot (unambigously) describe frequencies above $f_s/2$ in discrete time domain, so your description of the digital filter is inherently wrong or misleading! So: maybe the first step would be describing how you did the frequency analysis of the filter.

Comment: thanks for the addition! Gotta read this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is exactly the question I am raising. What could be the purpose of such a filter? I've added the complete python code to the question.

Comment: hey, your `calc_fft` function itself says it truncates everything above Nyquist. So, your plot cannot actually be showing something above it. Maybe an axis mislabeling?

Comment: I've added a plot which shows frequencies up to fs = 10Mhz

Comment: no, you did not. Your FFT cannot produce any information about frequencies above $f_s/2$; that's just not there in your discrete-time signal.

Comment: Okay, that's clear. That's why I omitted everything above fs/2 in the first place. I've tested my functions with sine waves, axis labeling seems to be correct for calc_fft function.

Comment: but it's demonstrably not correct :)

Comment: Could it be compensation for the roll-off in a CIC filter?

Comment: A **High-Pass Filter** is a filter that "amplifies" (w.r.t. other frequencies) the frequency components up at Nyquist.

Answer (score 5):

Such a filter is used to complete the frequency tiling of a strictly analytic (no negative frequencies) bandpass filterbank, as in CWT or (unusual) STFT. One will notice there's no way, with bell-shaped filters, to cover every frequency uniformly, *but* with such a filter.

[image]

It's readily seen, that unless one fitler peaks at Nyquist, then Nyquist can't be covered equally as other filters. However, merely having a peak at Nyquist isn't enough, as it lacks overlap from filters from the *right*, so it must amplify the input's Nyquist:

[image]

Still not uniform since we need more wavelets, but a slightly amplified Nyquist is necessary either way.

Uniform tiling enables [one-integral inversion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76239/50076), which itself enables algorithms like [synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076).

If the question is what such a filter can do *by itself* - well, it preserves peak center frequency at Nyquist while remaining strictly analytic, which is a sort of windowed analysis of AM/FM behavior near Nyquist. Though I've never encountered this. Also note @MattL's answer, the specific filter in question isn't great.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer below refers to the question in its original form which asked if a highpass filter with cut-off frequency at Nyquist makes any sense.**

---

I'm not sure why you think that the filter's cut-off frequency equals Nyquist.

The amplitude response of the given filter at Nyquist is

$$H\left(e^{j\pi}\right)=\sum_{n=-N/2}^{N/2}(-1)^nh[n]=1.375$$

So it does pass (actually amplifies) input frequencies at Nyquist.

The magnitude response looks like this:

[image]

The filter is just a relatively bad high-pass filter. However, its coefficients are all powers of $\frac12$, so it could be implemented very efficiently.

Comment: Okay, you are right. The filter amplifies frequencies at Nyquist. So, what could be an application for such a filter?

Comment: @JulianSarcher: I don't know, you know where you have those filter coeffs from.

Comment: The coeffs where given to me without context, that's why I am wondering about an application it could be used for.

Comment: @JulianSarcher: Might just be an exercise without any specific application in mind. As a highpass filter it's close to useless. Implementation can be very efficient due to all coefficients being powers of $\frac12$.

Comment: Yes, I recognized the implementation-friendly coefficients as well. Thanks.